# Iterating through a Class using a Function

Tags: python, function, class, iteration

I have a class created to store players in a game. I append the details of players in loop to create objects. I am confused though on how best to store details of the current player (first in the list) and then how to advance onto the next player using a function to do so. i.e. 1st player to 2nd; 2nd to 3rd and so on. Would it be better to use a dictionary instead of a class? Any ideas gratefully received.

```py
class Player:  # Create a class and structure
    score = 0

    def __init__(self, pnum, name, score, round):
        self.pnum = pnum
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        self.round = round


def CreatePlayers():

    a = int(input("Please enter the number of players\t "))

    player = []  # Create List Array

    for i in range(a):  # populate list using class
        player.append(Player(i, input("Enter Name:\t"), 0, 0))

    print("\n")

    for x in range(len(player)):  # print from class
        print(player[x].pnum, player[x].name, "\tScore:\t ", player[x].score,
              "\tRound:\t ", player[x].round)

    global current_player
    current_player = (player[0].pnum, player[0].name, player[0].score,
                      player[0].round)
```

Comment: You are already iterating over the players to print them out. What do you intend for each player next?

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. You are right I am iterating to print the players. Sorry for not being clear. My intention is to create dice based game where the current player can roll dice until he gets busted and then the code will advance to the next player making that player the new current.

Comment: Start by writing a function which takes a single player and allows that player to play as you describe. Then you can think about iterating over all players to play.

Comment: I think that makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood something, but looks like you could just assign a `Player` object to `current_player`:

```
# The current player will now be the first player
current_player = player[0]
# Iterate over all players in the order they're created:
for i in range(len(player)):
    current_player = player[i]
    print("Currently playing: player {}".format(i))
    current_player.some_method()
```

`.some_method()` can be responsible for updating the details of the player, if needed.

One thing that's a bit confusing in your code is that the array is called `player` and not `players` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking at this. You have given me a solid idea on how to proceed. Very much appreciated.